# Populate value in input field directly from redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

Can I set my input fields value to redux store value? Or may I need to copy the props to my local state for this?

```
<input
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      value={props.value}
 />
```

props.value is coming from react-redux's Connect.

But I can't change the value of input, I think this is because props is read only

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Was it helpful? If so I'd appreciate it if you upvote it and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can set value that way, it's correct. To change such input value you have to add `onChange` event handler that will dispatch an action updating corresponding value in Redux store (check React [doc about controlled form fields](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)):

```
<input
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      onChange={(event) => props.updateValueInRedux(event.target.value)}
      value={props.value}
 />
```

In above example the `updateValueInRedux` should be a function passed to component from Redux `connect` as property of `mapDispatchToProps` argument that will dispatch an action updating Redux state. It should look like that:

```
const mapStateToProps = {
    ...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateValueInRedux: (value) => {
            dispatch(someReduxUpdateAction(value));
        }
    }
};

const MyConnectedComponent = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Bartek said, your action could look like this:

```js
//Action Creator
export const UPDATE_VALUE = 'UPDATE_VALUE';

export function updateValueInRedux(value) {
  return ({
    type: UPDATE_VALUE,
    payload: value
  });
}

//Reducer
import {
  UPDATE_VALUE
} from './actions'; //[Or directory where your actions reside]

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  value: ''
}
export default
const UpdaterReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_VALUE:
      return { ...state,
        value: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

//Now 'value' will be available to all components that have the reducer state mapped to their properties
```