# ReactJS + Redux Edit form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following form:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { updateExpert, fetchExpert } from "../../store/actions/expertActions";

class ExpertForm extends Component {
  state = {
    expert: {}
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("ComponentWillMount");
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    console.log("Will fetch expert with id", id);
    this.props.fetchExpert(id);
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      expert: {
        ...this.state.expert,
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const newExpert = nextProps.expert;
    console.log("got new expert ", newExpert);
    this.setState({
      expert: nextProps.expert
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const originalExpert = this.props.expert;
    console.log("Expert before", originalExpert);
    // const updatedExpert = {

    // firstName: this.state.expert.firstName,
    // lastName: this.state.expert.lastName,
    // bio: this.state.expert.bio,
    // country: originalExpert.country,
    // interestIds: originalExpert.interestIds,
    // city: originalExpert.city,
    // summary: originalExpert.summary,
    // websiteText: originalExpert.websiteText,
    // websiteUrl: originalExpert.websiteUrl
    // };
    const updatedExpert = this.state.expert;
    console.log("Expert after", updatedExpert);
    //call action
    this.props.updateExpert(originalExpert.userId, updatedExpert);
  };

  render() {
    const { expert } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="card">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
            <div className="card-content">
              <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Update expert</h5>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="input-field  col s6">
                  <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                  <input
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    type="text"
                    id="firstName"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field col s6">
                  <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                  <input
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    type="text"
                    id="lastName"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="bio">Bio</label>
                <textarea
                  className="materialize-textarea"
                  id="bio"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="summary">Summary</label>
                <textarea
                  className="materialize-textarea"
                  id="summary"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="input-field col s6">
                  <label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
                  <textarea
                    className="materialize-textarea"
                    id="country"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field col s6">
                  <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
                  <textarea
                    className="materialize-textarea"
                    id="city"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="input-field col s6">
                  <label htmlFor="websiteText">Website text</label>
                  <textarea
                    className="materialize-textarea"
                    id="websiteText"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field col s6">
                  <label htmlFor="websiteUrl">Website URL</label>
                  <textarea
                    className="materialize-textarea"
                    id="websiteUrl"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-action">
              <div className="input-field">
                <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Update</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  expert: state.experts.item
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    updateExpert: (id, expert) => dispatch(updateExpert(id, expert)),
    fetchExpert: id => dispatch(fetchExpert(id))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, //mapstatetoprops
  mapDispatchToProps //mapdispatchtoprops
)(ExpertForm);
```

Now this form is used mostly to edit an item of the Expert type, not adding it. Which means I should prefill it with the information already stored in the database.

However when I try to set the value directly on an input like so:

```
<input
                value={expert.firstName}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                type="text"
                id="firstName"
              />
```

I get the following error:

```
index.js:1452 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

This is the ExpertList component from which the user accesses this ExpertForm:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ExpertItem from "./expert-item";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { fetchExperts } from "../../store/actions/expertActions";

class ExpertList extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("ComponentWillMount");
    this.props.fetchExperts();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("Rceived new props");
  }

  render() {
    const { experts } = this.props;

    const expertsDom = experts.map(expert => (
      <Link to={"/expert/edit/" + expert.userId}>
        <ExpertItem key={expert.userId} expert={expert} />
      </Link>
    ));
    return <div className="expert-list section">{expertsDom}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  experts: state.experts.items
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchExperts }
)(ExpertList);
```

These are my actions :

```
import {
  FETCH_EXPERTS,
  UPDATE_EXPERT,
  ADD_EXPERT,
  FETCH_EXPERT
} from "./types";

import axios from "../../network/axios";

export const createExpert = expert => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    //make async call to database

    dispatch({ type: ADD_EXPERT, expert: expert });
    // type: ADD_EXPERT;
  };
};

export const fetchExpert = id => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log("fetching expert with id ", id);
    axios
      .get("/connections/experts")
      .then(response => {
        const selectedExpert = response.data.filter(e => {
          return e.userId === id;
        })[0];
        console.log("ExpertsData ", selectedExpert);
        // const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
        //   experts: newExperts
        // });
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_EXPERT,
          payload: selectedExpert
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};

//Thunk allows us to call dispatch directly so that we can make async requests
//We can consider dispatch a resolver/promise, calling dispatch is just sending
//the data back
export const fetchExperts = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log("fetching");
    console.log("getstate ", getState());
    const accessToken = getState().auth.authInfo.accessToken;
    console.log("authToken ", accessToken);
    axios
      .get("/connections/experts")
      .then(response => {
        const newExperts = response.data;
        console.log("ExpertsData ", newExperts);
        // const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
        //   experts: newExperts
        // });
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_EXPERTS,
          payload: newExperts
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};

export const updateExpert = (id, expertData) => {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log("updating expert", id, expertData);
    axios
      .put("/experts/" + id, expertData)

      .then(response => {
        const updatedExpert = response.data;
        dispatch({
          type: UPDATE_EXPERT,
          payload: updatedExpert
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};
```

And this is my reducer:

```
import {
  FETCH_EXPERTS,
  UPDATE_EXPERT,
  FETCH_EXPERT
} from "../../store/actions/types";

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  item: {}
};

const expertReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_EXPERT:
      console.log("reducer fetch by id");
      return {
        ...state,
        item: action.payload
      };
    case FETCH_EXPERTS:
      console.log("reducer fetch");
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload
      };
    case UPDATE_EXPERT:
      console.log("reducer update");
      return {
        ...state,
        item: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default expertReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `value` property, You need to use `defaultValue` as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) in **Default Values** section if You want to have a default value for input field.

Comment: tried this but it seems to be putting the values of the previous item i clicked, i guess because i retrieve the item details in a rest call so the state is not updated, how can i fix this? somehow I wouldl ike to associate the values to the state, can i do that?

Comment: Yes, You can associate values with state like You did but also set default values in the way [Diego Nosi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116291/populate-value-in-input-field-directly-from-redux-store) have suggested and also using [this thread's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116291/populate-value-in-input-field-directly-from-redux-store)
second answer as a help guide.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `value` is `undefined` before Redux's state is loaded. You can solve this by giving it an empty string by default, something like this:

```
<input
    value={typeof expert.firstName === 'undefined' ? '' :  expert.firstName}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    type="text"
    id="firstName"
/>
```